# can we convert(revert) basic disk to dynamic after successfully installing ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

**I have two question**:  > Is it a mandatory to convert your disk to basic disk for installing ubuntu via option install ubuntu alongside windows 10?

> If I install ubuntu in basic disk. but after successful installation can I revert back to dynamic disk? will it affect any of my operation system(win 10 & ubuntu) ? 
>   I have tried to install but i didn't get those option.

Comment: What do you mean, basic or dynamic disk?

Comment: Please check out [here](http://www.partition-tool.com/easeus-partition-manager/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk.htm) and [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-basic-disk-to-dynamic-disk-windows-8-7). Before you start,  BACKUP !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Dynamic disks" relies on a Microsoft proprietary technology for which there's no support in Linux. As such, the answer is no, you can't convert to dynamic after installing Ubuntu as it will make your Ubuntu unbootable.

Comment: What if i convert fron dynamic to primary..will ubuntu boot?

Comment: Such operations aren't recommended even by Microsoft and they should know... Microsoft's position is "backup & reinstall" so...